# Storyboard - dynamically change height of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, storyboard, constraints

popup1

[image]

popup2

[image]

Is it possible to create single popup in storyboard & dynamically change - decrease/increase their height when error occurs (as shown in popup2)

I expect a correct approach to create such view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this easily is by using a vertical `UIStackView` in interface builder. For example, I have a simple stack view set up that contains two labels:

[image: vertical stack view]

Now, in your view controller you can simply set your error label to hidden or not and the stack view will dynamically take care of the rest. e.g:

Without hiding anything:

[image: error label showing]

Hiding error label:

```
[_errorLabel setHidden:YES];
```

[image: Error label hidden]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. Just put **Error view** in the middle of the popup and when error occurs change height of this view (error, `heightConstraint.constant = 50`, for example).

Then call

```
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[self.view updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```

But important to note, that you should configure all constraints correctly that the popup view is stretched properly.

Comment: Ok. I will try this.

Comment: But this will not increase the height of the container view aka the popup itself.